# understanding bit shifting in registers

Tags: embedded

I have to update the 32 bit register using these data 
which includes bit shifting, I am confused about two things:

1. Which is the LSB and which is the MSB,
2. what is this operator `|`

Given the expression:

```
3 << 0 | 
7 << 3 | 
1 << 6 | 
0 << 7 | 
1 << 7 | 
0 << 8 | 
0 << 10 |
0 << 11 | 
0 << 12 | 
0 << 13 | 
0 << 14
```

and the remaining 15 bits are `0`.

How is the data shifted, assuming initial bits in register to be 0's?

```
011 111 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 X.......X
```

or

```
x .....X 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 111 011
```

Comment: Please read tutorial about bit operations. There are likely other missing informations. It is useless to ask about single issue, as you will hardly get a consistent picture about this field. If you are using C, read a book. The better ones also cover bit operations with respect to C. For `|` and `<<`, note these are not the same for every language. Especially shift-operators might behave not as you actually expect - notably right shift.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The LSB (least-significant bit) is the bit whose value represents 1 (2^0) and the MSB is the bit whose value represents 2^(n-1), where n is the number of bits in the register. In general, when written out in binary, the MSB is the left-most bit and the LSB is the right-most bit. More often than not, the LSB is shown as bit 0 in hardware documentation, though I know one company that reverses the bit numbering so that the MSB is numbered 0.

`<<` is the C shift-left operator, shifting bit away from the LSB and toward the MSB. Therefore `7<<3` represents `111000` in binary.

`|` is the C bit-wise OR operator. This is used to combine values where resulting bits are one if either of the corresponding input bits is one.

Looking at your original value `3 << 0 | 7 << 3 | 1 << 6 | 0 << 7 | 1 << 7 | 0 << 8 | 0 << 10 | 0 << 11| 0 << 12 | 0 << 13 | 0 << 14`

`0000 0000 0000 0011` from `3<<0`

`0000 0000 0011 1000` from `7<<3`

`0000 0000 0100 0000` from `1<<6`

`0000 0000 0000 0000` from `0<<7`

etc.

This type of construct is typically used to describe a value going into a register noting the individual fields of the register.

Comment: "... that reverses the bit numbering so that the MSB is numbered 0." I saw this only in the 9ties in a PPC601 documentation. Very confusing.